# ACPI PCC - Acer E5-511

Tags: boot, shutdown, acer, acpi

I bought a notebook ACER model Aspire E 15 (E5-511-C7NE). The default OS was windows 8.1, I have formatted it and installed Ubuntu 15.04.
If `ACPI` is ON I receive the message:

```
ACPI PCC probe failed.
starting version 219
dw_dmac INTL9C60:00: invalid resource
```

The fans stay crazy and linux never starts.

I did a test: I turned off `ACPI` and it work fine, but something stopped working:

- I can't reboot.
- I can't shutdown.

I tried running from terminal `shutdown -h 0`, it tried shutting down, the screen was down and stay total black, however the computer stayed ON.

I found others post about it more nothing solve my problem.

I have tested the commands using root access.

Comment: ACPI handles the physical shutdown/reboot operations, without it the laptop just halts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues with my Acer... In my searching, I found suggestions to blacklist some drivers. In particular, dw_mac and dw_mac_core. Try this...

`echo "blacklist dw_dmac" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

`echo "blacklist dw_dmac_core" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

I suggest this because of the "dw_mac... invalid resource" result when ACPI is on. It is also worth noting that this didn't help me, but I also never had that error.

source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1319149