# Ubuntu 14.04 installation stuck

Tags: 14.04, usb-installation

I am using an usb drive configured to install ubuntu on my laptop. The laptop is Acer Aspire E5 with Intel Celeron N2940, 4gb ram and 500 gb hdd, currently with windows 10. The usb installer was made with pendrivelinux with the fat32 system, in order to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. I have also disabled secure booting, but it seems the installer in stuck on this image:

[image: screenshot]

The dots are not turning on/off like at the start, and the cooler starts running for 5 seconds every half a minute.
Yes I'm sure I downloaded the iso properly, as this is the 3rd time I've redownloaded it and put it on the usb drive.
Please give me any solution, I'm willing to try what you propose and post results.
Thanks in advance.

Edit for steps:

1. turn on pc holding f12 to bring up the boot menu
2. obviously select the usb hdd
3. I get 4 choices: try ubuntu without installing, installing ubuntu, oem install and checking for defects.
4. by simply selecting install ubuntu and pressing enter, 5 dots appear and flash in order. After one minute, they stop. No language select, no nothing.
5. restart and go back to 3: I entered command editing and replaced the `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`, then f10 to boot.
6. big list of operations and initialisations etc. At one point it stops:

   ```
   [57.963662] dw_dmac INTL9C60:00: invalid resource.
   ```

Same thing, stuck with cooler starting to work from time to time.

[image: screenshot]

edit2: the computer didn't even want to boot the usb installer with the 32 bit (i386), the bios did not detect it. I did try twice. Both the original image and the steps are made with the amd64 version.

edit3: I looked up the problem and kept searching on the internet, when I stumbled on someone suggesting I use `ACPI=off`. I gave it a go and I did not get any more errors, although most laptop features got turned off, including the touch pad. Then I got the following error:

[image: screenshot]

[Here's the source for anyone interested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637616/acpi-pcc-acer-e5-511)

Comment: It didn't help much, I'm trying the i386 version now.

Comment: Please describe as precisely as possible, which of the proposed steps you performed and what their outcome was. Maybe we can spot the issue in that.

Comment: there you go, i added steps in the main post.

Comment: i386 version won't work with computers that came with Windows 8 or above. In other words those with UEFI type of BIOS.

Comment: I found out I can install Ubuntu 12.04, but still, if anybody has any idea on why can't I install 14.04, please tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like 32-64 bit problem. Just make sure that the machine on which you are doing the installation matches the download file in 32 - 64 bit.

Comment: it didn't even want to boot the usb installer with the 32 bit (i386), the bios did not detect it. I did try twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since your computer has 4 GB RAM, you should install the 64-bit version.
 As you are trying the **i386** version now, which is **32-bit**. 
Please go for **amd64** version which is 64-bit.
Hope that helps.